# Why can I sometimes not send ETH through Metamask? Contract is payable and address is correct

Tags: metamask

Why does metamask sometimes not allow me to send eth to contracts...this contract and the function I'm calling was marked payable. See below

[image: Here is an example]

Comment: Sometimes, certain functions within a contract may not support external calls or transactions. Even if the contract is marked as payable, specific functions within the contract might have restrictions on external payments. BTW, have you updated your Metamask?

Comment: Do you have the contract source? Is it always the same contract? To calculate the cost Metamask simulates the operation. If the simulation fail it shows a warning because it cannot calculate the cost, and it is likely the transaction will fail. The possible reasons to fail depends on the contract.